# sort on number that is embedded in a string field in mongodb collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have data stored like this in my mongo db collection.

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId
  "username": "username-7"
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId
  "username": "username-1"
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId
  "username": "username-5"
},
```

Is there a way of constructing a query that can sort the entries based on number that is postfixed to the `username-`?

Using Node.js + Express

Comment: That depends on whether *all* your `username` entries are of the form `username-xx` or whether there may also be others. (If yes, how shall the others be sorted?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straight way to do this, you can try a custom logic using aggregation pipeline query,

- `$split` to split string by "-" and it will return an array
- `$last` to get the last element that is number from the above split result
- `$toInt` to convert above return number to an integer type
- $sort to sort the result by `uid` in ascending order, 1 is for ascending and -1 is for descending

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      uid: {
        $toInt: {
          $last: { $split: ["$username", "-"] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { uid: 1 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iadYgu2X9ld)